# How to find current wallpaper image file path

Tags: cinnamon, wallpaper

I've got a folder full of images that I have set to a wallpaper slideshow and I'd like to be able to find the current image being displayed. I'm running Mint 20 Cinnamon 4.6.7, and using the standard wallpaper slideshow settings with all images located in the same folder.

Is there a command I can run, or a program you know of, that would allow me to locate the file currently being displayed as the desktop wallpaper? For example, back when I used Windows the program Display Fusion added a context menu item that would allow you to right-click on the desktop and 'Open Current Wallpaper Image In File Explorer'. Is there any way of emulating that feature?

Thanks

I came across a similar post from a while ago that was recommended to use this command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri
```

However, all I get in return is:

```
file:///path/to/the/file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gsettings get org.cinnamon.desktop.background picture-uri
```

or look around for it:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep background
```

Comment: for dark theme users, try "gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark".  Gnome Tweaks utility's wallpaper setting (on ubuntu 22.04 release) has a bug that always show the normal/light theme wallpaper URI

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark
```

This command works in both light and dark mode in Pop!_OS